# Meteor Mongo Collections not Deploying

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm working on deploying my first meteor app. The only issue I'm having is that my Collections are not deploying with the app.

There are no errors on the console, and when I type in the collection names into the console it seems as though they exist, yet no data.

How can I check the mongo db from a meteor deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you deploy your Meteor app (including with `meteor deploy`), just having `xx = new Meteor.Collection("xx");` won't create any collections.

You have to insert data on your server to create the collections

If you mean to meteor.com hosting you can use `meteor mongo xxx.meteor.com`, if it is your own database you would have to connect to it manually with a tool like [robomongo](http://robomongo.org) or the mongo shell (`mongo <host>:<port>/<dbname> -u <username> -p <password`>

If the data exists there but it is not visible with your app via the web browser, try adding back the `autopublish` package and if this works you may need to make a custom [publish](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish) rule for your data